# How to change \EUR to serif font?

Tags: eurosym

In my document I use a sans serif font for everything except math. How can I change the `\EUR` macro provided by the `eurosym` package so that something like `\EUR{1234}` print the numbers (and the symbol?) in serif font?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
I'm just a test line \EUR{12345}. % I want this to be serif font...

I'm just a test line \euro \(12345\). % ...like this!
\end{document}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: A simple (maybe not the best) solution is to define a shortcut for the commands `\textrm{\EUR{12345}}`. Or if you are not going to use it many times, simply type like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redefine the command on preamble, inserting the Roman font family (`\rmfamily`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\makeatletter
%% from eurosym.sty
\def\EUR#1{{\rmfamily\if@EURleft\euro\,\fi#1\if@EURleft\else\,\euro\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

I'm just a test line \EUR{12345}. % ...like this!
\end{document}
```

Or maybe define a new command, eg, `\rmEUR` so you don't loose the default one.

Comment: you are switching to \rmfamily for all the following text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, ops, well observed. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of loading `eurosym`, you can load `textcomp` and use the command `\texteuro`, or just type in €.  If the current 8-bit legacy font has that symbol (and most of the ones in a modern TeX distribution do), it will use that.  Otherwise, the package will try to fake it with `C` and `=`.

With a modern TeX engine, you can load `fontspec` and use the Unicode character.  The `\texteuro` command still works, for backward compatibility.  Only a few publishers still do not support modern fonts in 2019.

You might find the `\EUR` command useful enough to define yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Or:
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{parskip} % Removes the paragraph indentation.

\DeclareRobustCommand\EUR[1]{€\thinspace #1}

\begin{document}
\EUR{10} \textbf{\EUR 10} \textit{\EUR{10} \textbf{\EUR{10}}} \\
\textsf{\EUR{10} \textbf{\EUR 10} \textit{\EUR{10} \textbf{\EUR{10}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Euro font sample]

This uses the Euro symbol from the current font, followed by a thin, non-breaking space.  If you would rather use the German convention of putting the symbol after the amount, do it that way instead.  (`#1\thinspace €`)  If you want to switch conventions within the same document, that would be more complicated.